# BCEL code example to put "new Class[]{String.class}" on the stack

Tags: java, bytecode, bcel

I am looking for a BCEL code example on how to create an array of size 1 containing instances of java.lang.Class and initialize its only element with a reference to java.lang.String.class

in other terms, I am looking for a BCEL code sample to put "new Class[]{String.class}" on the stack.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to create a class file version 49 (Java 5) or higher, the required instruction sequence is:

[`iconst_1`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iconst_i)
[`anewarray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.anewarray)`java/lang/Class`
[`dup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dup)
[`iconst_0`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iconst_i)
[`ldc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ldc)`java.lang.String.class`
[`aastore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.aastore)

Now the only question left is how to generate that in *BCEL*. According to what I saw from [its website](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/manual.html), the generator code may look like this:

```
il.append(InstructionConstants.ICONST_1);
il.append(factory.createNewArray(Type.getType(Class.class), 1));
il.append(InstructionConstants.DUP);
il.append(InstructionConstants.ICONST_0);
il.append(new LDC(constantPoolGen.addClass(Type.getType(String.class))));
il.append(InstructionConstants.AASTORE);
```

Though I haven’t tested it.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately this throws: ClassGenException: Illegal type: class org.apache.bcel.generic.ObjectType

Comment: It seems that `factory.createConstant` can’t create `Class` constants. But I made some other mistakes in haste as well; I have fixed them now.